# Can I connect to my app engine VM instance from my computer with SSH?

Tags: cloud, google

1) Can I connect to my app engine VM instance from my computer with SSH ?

I speak well about the app engine part of google cloud platform.

For example, in my computer, I open a terminal, I enter

```
ssh root@ip
```

How to get the IP and the username for the app engine instance ? I Want to do the same thing that in the GCP Shell, but from my PC..

2) I have app engine and compute engine in my GCP panel. Are them interconnected themselves between or are they independent instances (app and compute) ?

Answer (score 2):

App Engine Flexible Environment is implemented on Compute Engine as auto scaling, auto updating, container hosting instances. It is reasonable to assume most of GCP uses Compute Engine for... compute, but for this one you see the instances in your project.

You may list instances with the API, and get a shell on them with [`gcloud  app instances ssh`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/instances/ssh).  There is limited need for this as App Engine's OS environment is updated for you.